# Changing Firefox Smooth Scroll Settings (Using About:Config) to Be Like Default IE 11 Smooth Scroll Settings

Tags: firefox, scrolling

I am trying to adjust the Firefox smooth scroll settings using about:config in order to achieve smooth scrolling like the default settings in Internet Explorer 11.  Is this possible?  Do you know which values to change, and what values to change them to?

Comment: How about describing how the browsers differ, for those who might not be using both?

Comment: The thing is, if I have to describe their behavior to someone verbally, chances are that person will not be able to supply the correct values.  I think only someone with actual experience with the browsers and solid knowledge of smooth scroll values will be able to help.  But to answer your question, IE 11 provides what I'd consider actual smooth scrolling experience, with very smooth arcs and residual scrolling.  Firefox "smooth scrolling" really isn't smooth at all.

Comment: \*Shrug\* I just thought that if you described it then perhaps people who don't use IE but are familiar with Firefox, which is the browser whose settings you want to modify, would still be able to suggest something. Oh well, hopefully you'll get an answer from someone who's an expert in *both* browsers and has "solid knowledge of smooth scroll values".

Comment: That's what I'm hoping for. There's no reason to solicit a bad answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've been attempting to get the same settings too. It seems the behavior can't be copied exactly just by tweaking the values since Edge uses some acceleration parameters that are not in Firefox.

However, here's the best I found.

```
general.smoothScroll.mouseWheel.durationMaxMS = 100
general.smoothScroll.mouseWheel.durationMinMS = 100
general.smoothScroll.pages.durationMaxMS = 100
general.smoothScroll.pages.durationMinMS = 100
general.smoothScroll.pixels.durationMaxMS = 100
general.smoothScroll.pixels.durationMinMS = 100
general.smoothScroll.scrollbars.durationMaxMS = 100
general.smoothScroll.scrollbars.durationMinMS = 100
general.smoothScroll.stopDecelerationWeighting = 1
```

[Here's an explanation of all the values.](https://web.archive.org/web/20171214193241/http://12bytes.org/tech/firefox-scroll-tweak)

Comment: broken link above. maybe this one? http://12bytes.org/tech/firefox/firefox-tweaks-and-fixes-and-things

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to have resurfaced with Firefox 82 (Oct 2020). These seems to
be the problem values:

```
general.smoothScroll.mouseWheel.durationMaxMS 200
general.smoothScroll.mouseWheel.durationMinMS 50
```

Reverting to these previous values seems to have resolved the issue:

```
general.smoothScroll.mouseWheel.durationMaxMS 400
general.smoothScroll.mouseWheel.durationMinMS 200
```

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1679701